# Develop Web services using Axis and deploy it as war file

Tags: apache-axis

We need to develop a Webservice using Apache Axis 2 and deploy this Application as a war file in glassfish server, so that it would be accessable to our service consumers from there.

I am really confused with this as Axis2 applications are being packaged as `.aar` extension.

And more over, I am also new to Axis Webservices, and this has got a lot of versions (don't know what version to pick) and some examples are using AxisServlet and some are simple being deployed as `.aar` .
Could anybody please guide me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Axis2 is 1.6.0.

You can use the Axis2 .war distribution for this. You can deploy the .war file in glass fish and put the .aar files under the services folder under the WEB-INF folder.

if glassfish does not expand the .war files then you can unpack the axis2 .war file put your .aar file to services folder repack and deploy.

you can find a axis2 user guide from the axis2 [site](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) and [here](http://wso2.org)